# difference between @FindAll and @FindBys annotations in webdriver page factory

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Please explain the difference between @FindAll and @FindBys annotations in webdriver page factory concept.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

We can use these annotations in those cases when we have more than a single criteria to to identify one or more WebElement objects.

**@FindBys :** When the required WebElement objects need to match all of the given criteria use @FindBys annotation

**@FindAll :** When required WebElement objects need to match at least one of the given criteria use @FindAll annotation

Usage:

```
@FindBys( {
   @FindBy(className = "class1")
   @FindBy(className = "class2")
} )
private List<WebElement> elementsWithBoth_class1ANDclass2;
```

Here List elementsWithBothclass1ANDclass2 will contain any WebElement which satisfies both criteria.

```
@FindAll({
   @FindBy(className = "class1")
   @FindBy(className = "class2")
})
private List<WebElement> elementsWithEither_class1ORclass2
```

Here List elementsWithEither_class1ORclass2 will contain all those WebElement that satisfies any one of the criteria.

Comment: This answer is unclear, probably better to read the ones below.

Comment: add missing commas between array elements.

Answer (score 23):

`@FindAll` can contain multiple `@FindBy` and will return all the elements which matches any `@FindBy` in a single list.

Example:

```
@FindAll({
@FindBy(id = "one"),
@FindBy(id = "two")
})
public List<WebElement> allElementsInList;
```

Whereas,

`@FindBys` will return the elements depending upon how `@FindBy` specified inside it.

```
 @FindBys({
    @FindBy(id = "one"),
    @FindBy(className = "two")
    })
    public List<WebElement> allElementsInList;
```

Where `allElementsInList` contains all the elements having `className="two"` inside `id="one"`

Answer (score 11):

to put it in simple words, @FindBys have AND conditional relationship among the @FindBy whereas @FindAll has OR conditional relationship.

Comment: Thank you, Short and clear, this should be the accepted answer in my opinion, I also think the annotations should be renamed to be self descriptive instead of this ambiguity.

Comment: Be careful! It's not as simple as that. When using \@FindBys the \@FindBy are chained and the condition is "inside" not AND, as Vignesh Paramasivam says below.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the [JavaDocs](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html):

Annotation Type FindBys

```
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Target(value={FIELD,TYPE})
public @interface FindBys

Used to mark a field on a Page Object to indicate that lookup should use a series of @FindBy tags in a chain as described in ByChained Eg:

 @FindBys({@FindBy(id = "foo"),
           @FindBy(className = "bar")})
```

Annotation Type FindAll

```
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Target(value={FIELD,TYPE})
public @interface FindAll

Used to mark a field on a Page Object to indicate that lookup should use a series of @FindBy tags It will then search for all elements that match any of the FindBy criteria. Note that elements are not guaranteed to be in document order. Eg:

 @FindAll({@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "foo"),
           @FindBy(className = "bar")})
```

Comment: +1 for the useful references, though unable to find easy to understand things like that!!