# How to implement List FindALL webelement

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

```
<i>
@FindAll(@FindBy(xpath = ".//input[contains(@name,'adv_xfer_fields') 
and contains(@name,'::amounts')]"))
List <WebElement> amounts;
</i>
```

I have dynamic web-table in the input field, Ideally I need to pass value to this. But I'm not sure how to implement this?

```
public List<WebElement> getAllAmounts() {
    return amounts;
}
```

Please help

Comment: You have only one FindBy criterion, what is the need for using FindAll? Refer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914156/difference-between-findall-and-findbys-annotations-in-webdriver-page-factory

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, I don't see any error in your tried out code but definately we can be a bit structured more precise as follows :

```
        @FindAll({@FindBy(xpath = ".//input[contains(@name,'adv_xfer_fields')]"),
                @FindBy(xpath = ".//input[contains(@name,'::amounts')]")}) 

        List <WebElement> amounts;
```

As per the documentation, **`FindAll`** is used to mark a field on a Page Object to indicate that lookup should use a series of `@FindBy` tags. It will then search for all elements that match any of the `FindBy` criteria though elements are not guaranteed to be in document order.

Comment: The problem with this, while it is a valid FindAll, the original post has an "and" condition, and your example provides an "or" condition, since you stated it would find -any- of the FindBy's.  I think the solution is just to remove the outer FindAll and keep the rest of the original poster's locator.