# What is the use of @FindBys and @FindAll

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

For understating, i used [this](https://www.ontestautomation.com/findby-strategies-for-selenium-explained/)

Also,[@FindBys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914156/difference-between-findall-and-findbys-annotations-in-webdriver-page-factory) have AND conditional whereas @FindAll has OR conditional and i tried this below code,

```
@FindBys(

        {
            @FindBy(name="username"),
            @FindBy(name="password")

        }


        )

List<WebElement> totWeAnd;

@FindAll(

        {

            @FindBy(name="username"),
            @FindBy(name="password")

        }

        )
List<WebElement> totWeOr;
```

As expected,totWeAnd returned 0 WebElements and totWeOr returned 2 WebElements.
but the same above thing can be achieved by using **FinBy(xpath="")** as below,

```
    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@name='username' and @name='password']")
    List<WebElement> totWE_And;

    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@name='username' or @name='password']")
    List<WebElement> totWE_OR;
```

so what is the use of @FindBys,@FindAll and when we should use it?

Answer (score 1):

The logic in the article is not correct. Each `FindBy mentioned in the [FindBys][1] or [FindAll][1] annotation` refers to a specific element that matches the criterion, rather than the 'OR' and 'AND' combination of criterion.

[@FindBys](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/ByChained.java) - Returns a chain of element(s) matching the sequence of elements returned by each FindBy.

[@FindAll](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/ByAll.java) - Returns all the element(s) matching each element returned by each FindBy.

Easiest way is to test with some code. Check the source code of the links especially the `findElements()` method.

Below is a **simple HTML for testing**.

```
<div id='level1elem1' name='LEVEL1 ELEMENT1'>
    <div id='level2elem1' name='LEVEL2 ELEMENT1'>
    </div>
    <div id='level2elem2' name='LEVEL2 ELEMENT2'>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PageObject class.** Refer to the comments before the element variables.

```
public class FindPageObject {

    private WebDriver driver;

    //This will match an element (id of level2elem1) inside a parent element (id of level1elem1).
    //Refer to test - testFindBys.
    //Return a POSITIVE match.
    @FindBys({
        @FindBy(id="level1elem1"),
        @FindBy(id="level2elem1")
    })
    private WebElement singleFindBys;

    //This NEEDS TO MATCH an element (id of level1elem1) inside a parent element (id of level2elem1).
    //Refer to test - testFindBysRev.
    //Return a NoSuchElementException as element heirarchy is not present.
    @FindBys({
        @FindBy(id="level2elem1"),
        @FindBy(id="level1elem1")
    })
    private WebElement singleFindBysRev;

    //This will match the first element that matches any of the 3 criterion.
    //Refer to test - testFindByAll.
    //Return a POSITIVE match of top most element (id of level1elem1).
    @FindAll({
        @FindBy(id="level1elem1"),
        @FindBy(id="level2elem1"),
        @FindBy(id="level2elem2")
    })
    private WebElement singleFindAllUI;

    //This will match the first element that matches any of the 3 criterion.
    //In this case the inner elemnts FindBy are placed first.
    //Refer to test - testFindByAllRev.
    //Return a POSITIVE match of top most element (id of level2elem2).
    @FindAll({
        @FindBy(id="level2elem2"),
        @FindBy(id="level2elem1"),
        @FindBy(id="level1elem1")
    })
    private WebElement singleFindAllUIRev;

    //This will match all the elements for each criterion.
    //Refer to test - testFindByAllMultiple.
    //Return a POSITIVE match of a list of all the elements of size 3.
    @FindAll({
        @FindBy(id="level1elem1"),
        @FindBy(id="level2elem1"),
        @FindBy(id="level2elem2"),
    })
    private List<WebElement> multipleFindAll;

    //This will match all the elements for each criterion.
    //Element(id of level1elem1 & name LEVEL1 ELEMENT1) will be returned twice as it matches the first and last findby.
    //Refer to test - testFindByAllMultipleDuplicate.
    //Return a POSITIVE match of a list of all the elements of size 4.
    @FindAll({
        @FindBy(id="level1elem1"),
        @FindBy(id="level2elem1"),
        @FindBy(id="level2elem2"),
        @FindBy(name="LEVEL1 ELEMENT1"),
    })
    private List<WebElement> multipleFindAllDuplicate;

    //This will match all the elements that satisfy the xpath.
    //Though it has 4 matchers returns only 3 elements.
    //Refer to test - testXpathAlls.
    //Return a POSITIVE match of a list of all the elements of size 3.
    @FindBy(xpath="//div[@id='level1elem1' or @id='level2elem2' or @id='level2elem1' or @name='LEVEL1 ELEMENT1']")
    private List<WebElement> xpathAlls;


    public FindPageObject(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }


    public String getSingleFindBys() {
        return singleFindBys.getAttribute("name");
    }

    public String getSingleFindBysRev() {
        return singleFindBysRev.getAttribute("name");
    }

    public String getSingleFindAll() {
        return singleFindAllUI.getAttribute("name");
    }

    public String getSingleFindAllRev() {
        return singleFindAllUIRev.getAttribute("name");
    }

    public int getSizeMultiple() {
        return multipleFindAll.size();
    }

    public int getSizeMultipleDuplicate() {
        return multipleFindAllDuplicate.size();
    }

    public int getSizeMultipleXpaths() {
        return xpathAlls.size();
    }
}
```

**junit test class.**

```
public class FindTest {

    private static WebDriver driver;


    @Test
    public void testFindBys() {
        FindPageObject fpo = new FindPageObject(driver); 
        assertEquals("LEVEL2 ELEMENT1", fpo.getSingleFindBys());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindBysRev() {
        FindPageObject fpo = new FindPageObject(driver); 
        thrown.expect(NoSuchElementException.class);
        fpo.getSingleFindBysRev();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByAll(){
        FindPageObject fpo = new FindPageObject(driver); 
        assertEquals("LEVEL1 ELEMENT1", fpo.getSingleFindAll());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByAllRev(){
        FindPageObject fpo = new FindPageObject(driver); 
        assertEquals("LEVEL2 ELEMENT2", fpo.getSingleFindAllRev());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByAllMultiple(){
        FindPageObject fpo = new FindPageObject(driver); 
        assertEquals(3, fpo.getSizeMultiple());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByAllMultipleDuplicate(){
        FindPageObject fpo = new FindPageObject(driver); 
        assertEquals(4, fpo.getSizeMultipleDuplicate());
    }

    @Test
    public void testXpathAlls(){
        FindPageObject fpo = new FindPageObject(driver); 
        assertEquals(3, fpo.getSizeMultipleXpaths());
    }

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "Path to chromedriver");

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("Local path to html");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tear() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Regarding usage, have never used either as it is easier to create a css or xpath. Also performance is better as the number of times page is queried is greater.