# getAttribute("value") returns 0

Tags: java, selenium

I want to click on an element which is from a list. I am using  getAttribute("value") to get the text, but it returns 0, hence it is not clicking the element. Please help.

DOM structure

```
<ol class ="class1">
<li value="foo1" class="class2"> 
<li value="foo2" class="class2">
</ol>
```

Xpath:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//ol[@class='class1']/li")
List<WebElement> tagList;
```

I have tried getText() but it returns the text along with unknown character, as the element has icons along with the text.

This is my code

```
public void selectTag() {
        addReservationBtn.click();
        tags.click();
        for(WebElement li : tagList) {
    // System.out.println(li.getAttribute("value"));
            if (li.getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase("foo2")) {
                li.click();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your ol element's class name doesn't have closing quotations, is that a typo or...?

Comment: Also you can get that element by including value attribute in xpath expression, thus eliminating the for loop.

Comment: What is 0? the string returned from `getAttribute("value")` or `tagList` size?

Comment: @MilanMiljus   Sorry, that was a typo, edited now.

Comment: 0 is the string returned from getAttribute("value"). Used this to know what it was reurning. System.out.println(li.getAttribute("value"));

Comment: @MilanMiljus  There are more <li> tags inside <ol>,the above dom is a sample. Hope I am using the correct Xpath for iterating elements. Or should I just removed /li from the Xpath? @FindBy(xpath = "//ol[@class='class1']")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As text contains unknown characters so

```
  li.getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase("foo2")
```

will not work as both string not equal.

You can try contains like

```
  li.getAttribute("value").contains("foo2")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me fixing the test. But I still would like to know why the getAttribute("value") was returning 0.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You are using `@FindBy` which only returns the first element found by the given locator. Use `@FindBys` to get all the elements found by the given locator.</s>

> As the previous answer was wrong I've striked it but kept it for
>   the clarification of the comments.

You can directly get the second element without using the for loop by

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//ol[@class='class1']/li[@class='class2']")
```

---

The `getAttribute()` method returns `null` if there are no attribute found and returns empty when there is an attribute but it doesn't contain any value.

Comment: This is wrong, `@FindBy` is used for lists as well. [@FindBys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914156/difference-between-findall-and-findbys-annotations-in-webdriver-page-factory) has other use.

Comment: @Guy - You are right `@FindBy` works for `List` also

Comment: @Guy You are right. It was wrong. I've striked the answer but kept it for this comment context.

Comment: @SAhmed   The DOM I have given is a dummy as I am not supposed to paste it here because of confidentiality. The list has more <li> tags that's why I am using loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think reason for your problem may be 
1. Wrong xpath or 2. Waits

```
// get second <li> using correct xpath
@FindBy(xpath = "//ol[@class='class1']/li[2]")
List<WebElement> tagList;


public void selectTag() {
        addReservationBtn.click();
        tags.click();
        // waitforliTextToAppearAfterClick();
        if (tagList.get(1).getAttribute("value").trim().equalsIgnoreCase("foo2")) {
        tagList.get(1).click(); 
  }
```