# Can Selenium Java locate a webelement using multiple locators at a single point of time?

Tags: java, selenium, ui-automation

A webelement can be identified in different ways using their different attributes.
Just to avoid the test flakiness, is there a way to list multiple ways of locating the same element
id=username
name=user
And the selenium will try to find the element using one or the other locator listed?

I know that in xpath we have AND and OR operators, which can be used

Comment: I hope this answer can help you. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914156/difference-between-findall-and-findbys-annotations-in-webdriver-page-factory/25915562)

Comment: `@FindBys` or `@FindAll`